# What is the length of [BC]?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let A , B and C be 3 points of a circle (c)

P is the intersection of two tangents of the circle in points B and C

Let (AB)//(CP) and AB=3 and BP=4 
What is the length of BC

Can someone give hint ! 
Im blocked , the problem is that i don't know to start my proof

I see that BPC is triangle such that CP=BP

We suppose that ABPC is quadrilater parallelogram

Comment: This is not geometric topology.

Comment: @BalarkaSen you are right

Comment: What do you mean about the last sentence? Is it a given or your finding. A rough sketch shew that XBPC is a parallelogram where X is on BA extended and is 4 units from B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

It is not difficult to show that XBPC is a parallelogram. In fact, it is a rhombus because $PB = BX = 4.$

$\alpha = \beta$ (tangent properties)

$\beta = \gamma$ (alternate angles)

$\beta = \delta$ (angles in alternate segment)

$∴ \triangle PBC \sim \triangle CBA$

$∴ \dfrac {PB}{BC} = \dfrac {BC}{BA}$

That is,   $\dfrac {4}{BC} = \dfrac {BC}{3}$

Result follows.

Comment: I haven't finished my edit. Why the down-vote?